# Custom fields not exposed by Salesforce Enterprise WSDL via C#

Tags: c#, wsdl, salesforce

I'm in the early stages of creating an intermediary DLL in C# to keep our locally stored data in sync with that in our Salesforce instance. I've generated the Enterprise WSDL for our organisation, and added that as a web reference in the project. The custom objects have been pulled through as expected, but they only seem to expose the standard fields.

As an example, see the below from the generated WSDL:

```
<complexType name="PCA_Account__c">
<complexContent>
<extension base="ens:sObject">
<sequence>
<element name="AccountStatus__c" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
```

...

And the following whilst trying to access the "AccountStatus__c" from an instantiated "PCA_Account__c" object:

```
var acc = new PCA_Account__c();
acc.AccountStatus__c = "Foo";
```

Visual Studio is complaining that it "cannot resolve symbol 'AccountStatus__c'".

I've checked both the object- and field-level security, and both are currently set to allow editing by any user.

Is there something I'm missing as to how I should Get/Set this and other properties?

I've tried reflecting over the "PCA_Account__c" type to get all the properties, and they're not there, so I'm a little stuck as to where to go from here...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you see the required fields if you connect to an external tool like [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) with the same user credentials?

Comment: I haven't tried any other tools in truth, will give it a shot...

Comment: Is there any chance the WSDL in the web reference is old and should be refreshed (or however you force VisualStudio to regenerate the stub classes)? It's quite often forgotten step, you fix the field level security on the fields, you download new WSDL, you forget to force "consuming" it fresh... Or maybe you have some kind of caching there?

Comment: It's all up to date, I didn't trust the "Update Web Reference" in VS, so removed, redownloaded, and reimported the WSDL, no change.